# Passing data between objects attributes of an object

Tags: java, swing, oop, object, graphics

Currently trying to make a graphic clock in JAVA, I'm dealing with a problem of "communication" between elements. Indeed, my architecture is visible underneath and is composed of 3 classes:

[image]

The drawer is used as a "container" by grouping the various elements which concern the data (the clock class which only allows to store the current time) and the graphic (the JFrame as well as clockPanel).

ClockPanel is the class that should allow to draw the clock (for the moment I was able to draw the static elements, as visible below).

[image]

My problem is how to pass the clock data to ClockPanel in order to draw the clock hands.

I was thinking of passing the clock to ClockPanel but it seems pretty obvious that this is not the solution to choose, it would make the drawer useless.

So I can't see how to make the link between these two elements.
I try to be as clean as possible in order to acquire the best possible reflexes for the future.

I thought for a while that my current structure is completely wrong, which is causing my problem.

Below are code snippets from the drawer and the paintComponent function of the clockPanel:

```
public void initDraw() {
        clockWindow = new JFrame();

        clockWindow.setTitle(getTitle());//Définit un titre pour notre fenêtre
        clockWindow.setSize(getSize(), getSize());//Définit sa taille, elle sera carrée car deux fois size en W et H
        clockWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Nous demandons maintenant à notre objet de se positionner au centre
        clockWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Termine le processus lorsqu'on clique sur la croix rouge
        clockWindow.setResizable(false);//L'utilisateur ne peux pas redimensionner la fenetre
        clockWindow.setVisible(true);//Et enfin, la rendre visible

        clockPanel =  new ClockPanel(m_clock);
        clockWindow.setContentPane(clockPanel);

}
```

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        m_radiusWhiteCircle = (getWidth()/2)-40; //on prend un rayon qui va donner un cercle qui prend quasiment toute la fenetre
        m_centerX = m_centerY = getWidth()/2; //dans le contexte actuel, la fenetre est carrée, donc qu'on prenne widh ou height c'est pareil (a separe en deux opération si on change)
        System.out.println(getHeight());

        this.setBackground(new Color(160, 196, 235)); //on défini le fond du JPanel
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);// le prochaine cercle sera noir
        int[] blackCircleSquare = convertCircleCoordsToSquareCoords(m_centerX, m_centerY, m_radiusWhiteCircle + 10); //on convertit les coordonées de notre cercle afin d'obtenir ceux du coin gauche du carré qui va contenri notre cerle
        g.fillOval(blackCircleSquare[0],blackCircleSquare[1],blackCircleSquare[2],blackCircleSquare[2]);//On dessine le contour de l'horlorge en prenant le centre de la fenetre et un rayon un peu supérieur au cercle "principal"

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);//le prochain cercle sera blanc
        int[] whiteCircleSquare = convertCircleCoordsToSquareCoords(m_centerX, m_centerY, m_radiusWhiteCircle);
        g.fillOval(whiteCircleSquare[0],whiteCircleSquare[1],whiteCircleSquare[2],whiteCircleSquare[2]);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        int[] greenCircleSquare = convertCircleCoordsToSquareCoords(m_centerX, m_centerY, 10);
        g.fillOval(greenCircleSquare[0],greenCircleSquare[1],greenCircleSquare[2],greenCircleSquare[2]);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN,20));
        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++) {
            int xHour = (int)(m_centerX+(m_radiusWhiteCircle-15)*Math.cos(i*INVARIABLE_ANGLE_HOUR - INVARIABLE_DECALAGE));
            int yHour = (int)(m_centerY+(m_radiusWhiteCircle-20)*Math.sin(i*INVARIABLE_ANGLE_HOUR - INVARIABLE_DECALAGE));
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(i),xHour,yHour);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the following steps:

1. You can use the classes already existing for time handling (classes in `java.time` package). I know it might at a glance seem more complex than the handmade class `Clock`, but it has more potential. In the long run, you may be forced to learn about it because you will need that potential. We have more chances someone else, who will maintain our code in the future, to know about the already existing API and not our own handmade classes. And also, by learning it now, you can also start using it now.
2. As for the class diagram, I think one can say that the objects are: time, graphical representation of time and a window (having a graphical representation of time). So that would lead me to subclass an `Icon` for the graphical representation of the time, use the already existing time handling classes (or create them if, and only if, they did not already exist) and finally the window (which already exists as `JFrame`).
3. So, how to supply an `Icon` to the window?... Via a `JLabel`.
4. Then create a `Timer` object to update the `JLabel`'s clock icon/representation every so often (as needed).

Follows example demonstrating code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static class ClockIcon implements Icon {
        @Override
        public void paintIcon(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y) {
            //The clock's painting goes here...
            g.fillOval(x, y, getIconWidth() - 1, getIconHeight() - 1);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN.darker());
            g.drawString(LocalTime.now().toString(), x + 14, y + 5 + getIconHeight() / 2);
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return 100; //The clock's width goes here...
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return 100; //The clock's height goes here...
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            final JLabel label = new JLabel(new ClockIcon(), SwingConstants.CENTER);

            final Timer engine = new Timer(500, e -> label.repaint());
            engine.setRepeats(true);
            engine.start();

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clock");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(label);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

For a simple tutorial on how to use the time classes I would suggest [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro). If you are more curious, you can start at the documentation of the package [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Hope it helps.

Some notes: I would suggest you to not be in a hurry of accepting an/my answer if it does not help you as much as you wanted. Feel free to ask first for clarifications in the comments or simply wait more time for more reputable sources to answer your question. My opinion is that in your case you don't have a complex class diagram to work with: just subclass `Icon` and give this to a `JLabel` and a `Timer`. Finally, I should say that, posting an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question, of what you tried, helps getting better answers.

Comment: Thanks for that big response with proposition of solution !!

I will watch it with interest, evaluate and try some things !
Thanks for all the advices you provided here !

Comment: Thank you! Another thing to note is that I tested the proposed solution with timer delay equal to 1000ms (1 sec) in order to update it exactly every 1 sec, but the milliseconds of each print out of the time showed that exactly 1 sec is not enough. The timer's delay should be less than 1 sec in order to account for the additional delay introduced by the timer's action listener itself as well as the repainting. That's why if you see the timer's delay in my example is 500ms, not near 1000.